# How should I allocate my stats to maximize damage on a split scaling weapon?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I assume (but correct me if I'm wrong), that if I had a weapon that had something like E scaling on Strength but B on Dexterity, I should just raise Dexterity to the softcap before putting points in Strength.

However, when the scaling is evenly split, say C/C, should I alternate which stat I raise every level, or will that bet the same as just raising one to the softcap and then the other? I want to keep my damage maximized as I level up.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the requirements to wield the weapon is different to scaling. Requirements are clearly defined (usually in STR/DEX) as digits, eg: S - 25, D - 15.

Secondly, scaling works from S through to E, S being the best, E being the worst. The scale goes S, A, B, C, D, E.

Finally, (this is going from the DkS2 values, though I don't see why the DkS3 values should differ too greatly), the bonuses granted from scaling go like this:

- S  140%–200%
- A  100%–139%
- B   75%– 99%
- C   50%– 74%
- D   25%– 49%
- E    1%– 24%

So, if you have a weapon that has an S scaling, you will be granted between a 140 - 200% bonus for that stat.

Again, if you have a weapon that has a C/C scaling in STR/DEX, it doesn't matter which stat you level up, it will still only grant you a 50% - 74% upgrade, regardless of which stat you level up.

EG:

+15 Club, 24 Strength, 2 hands. 
◾ BasePhysical: 182 
◾ StrengthScaling: 132% (A) 
◾ StrengthRating: 76% (effectively 36 Strength because two-handing) 
BonusStrength = BasePhysical × StrengthScaling × StrengthRating BonusStrength = 183 × 132% × 76% ≈ 183 
PhysicalRating = BasePhysical + BonusStrength + BonusDexterity + BonusChaosPhysical PhysicalRating = 182 + 183 + 0 + 0 = 365 
TotalAttackRating = PhysicalRating + MagicRating + FireRating + LightningRating TotalAttackRating = 365 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 365

[Source](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Parameter_Bonus)

Comment: So, because bonuses from Strength and Dexterity are additive, as Ben describes, you should always raise the greater-scaled stat first to the max (and there is no difference if both stats have equal scaling). But I see StrengthRating is multiplicative, so whatever that is (I don't play Souls) it should be factored into Strength Scaling.

Comment: This answer is informative but kind of misses the actual question. If the scaling is equal you CAN raise both stats evenly since the weapon will scale the same either way. But doesn't mean you should because your next weapon might not be scaled evenly.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the weapon you were using. In some cases, if the scaling is at an E or even a D (personal approach) then it may not be worth increasing both stats as the gains would be small, so quite rightly, only level the stat that will increase the damage significantly at first.

If you were to use a weapon which scaled well in both stats (for instance, a refined Lothric Knight Sword Str: B  Dex: B), then leveling both stats to 40 would bring the damage via scaling slightly over its soft cap. I believe which stat you bring up first is purely person choice, but if you were to use low-level pyromancies or spells, then dexterity will increase your casting speed at 36.